# Thunderbird - Error: Can't add a login with null or empty password

Tags: windows-10, thunderbird, smtp

On my Windows 10 Outlook keeps asking for SMTP login which 100% works (tested in Browser) and it did work in the past. Thunderbird same issue and the thunderbird error console gives me this error "Error: Can't add a login with null or empty password"

Because both programs have problems with authentication I assume the issue is somehow in Windows 10.

How can completely unset my login data and reenter it? Or at least how can I test if the SMTP connection works?

[image]

Comment: For Thunderbird : Have you removed the password to this site from menu *Tools > Options > Privacy & Security > Saved Passwords...*?

Comment: It re-asks for my password, re-asks for permission (I guess a OAuth2 thing) and then it checks forever and keeps throwing this errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to enable "Less secure apps" in Gmail / Google Mail. That solved my issue. I got an email notification about that. It was not super clear how to fix it but when you are logged in with your browser to Google Mail you can simply search for "less secure" and set the Toggle Switch to enabled. Then it worked again with Outlook 2013.

Comment: A number of email providers have changed login requirements, e.g. AOL.com, as well as GMail. Some are simple to fix, as was GMail, others are so onerous, such as restricting access to a single device, that I've dropped those accounts.,